# Android 10 - Connect Wi-Fi network programmatically

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, android-10.0

Requirement: I want to connect to Wi-Fi network with internet.

Present implementation: I am able to connect and use Wi-Fi using WifiManager class. but it works for android versions < 10, for android 10 I am not able to fulfill my requirement.

Please help me and suggest possible way outs to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091968/connect-to-wifi-android-q

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I have tried this code, my wifi connect by using this code without internet. I want to connect wifi with internet. So, please suggest any other option or solution in this code for internet. Thanks for the response.

Comment: What do you mean by connect Wi-Fi with internet and not android?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf This code I tried on Android 10, I had a successful connection but without internet. I have lost internet access.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138335744 follow this link for more details

Comment: @UsamaAltaf This link does not work.